# What to call a graduate in Engineering Physics?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, professions

What to call a graduate in Engineering Physics based on the academic background, and why is it called Engineering Physics and no Physical Engineer (like mechanical/electrical engineering)?

https://physics.stanford.edu/undergraduate-program/bs-engineering-physics
https://www.engineering.cornell.edu/academics/undergraduate/curriculum/Majors/eng_phy.cfm
http://engineeringscience.berkeley.edu/engineering-physics/

Physicist Engineer?
Engineer Physicist?
Physics Engineer?
Engineer Physics?

Comment: [Qualified ***Engineering Physicists***, with a degree in Engineering Physics, can work professionally as Engineers and/or Physicists in the high technology industries and beyond, becoming domain experts in multiple engineering and scientific fields.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_physics) - Wikipedia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they get a job as an engineer, they're an engineer (if they don't need a license to use that title in their locality). If they get a job as a physicist, they're a physicist.

It's also possible they're a salesperson or lawyer or dish-washer with an engineering physics degree.

Comment: you can say mechanical/electrical/civil/... engineer. What I am asking is how to qualify the engineer professional based on the academic background.

Comment: @kkkk, it depends what position they get. If they get hired to be an electrical engineer, they're an electrical engineer (with a background in engineering physics). If they get hired to be a mechanical engineer, they're a mechanical engineer (with a background in engineering physics).

Comment: More likely, they get hired to be a "systems engineer" or "staff scientist" or something non-specific, since they got a generalist degree rather than an in-depth one in any specific engineering field.

Comment: Just for curiosity, have you studied engineering physics?

Comment: No, but I had a college friend who got that degree...he's the "laywer" example.

Comment: Hope you don't know the dish-washer example, otherwise i might have chosen a wrong academic path xD. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for a moment that we are simply applying logic to come up with an analogy to existing degrees, as you suggest in your question that we might do.

If it were primarily an engineering degree with a specialization in physics, then the term would be "engineer" with an adjective, analogous to "mechanical engineer". Your graduate might have to be known as a "physicist engineer".

On the other hand, if it were primarily a physics degree with a specialization in engineering. So the term would be "physicist" with an adjective, analogous to "nuclear physicist". Your graduate might be an "engineering physicist".

But this is reason in a vacuum. It turns out that this is commonly a dual-degree program, not a physics or engineering degree with a concentration, so really neither term is primary. And it's not a traditional field, which means you might expect that not everyone agrees yet on terminology. These facts are borne out by what web searches return. The actual terms in use vary widely, and there is not one best answer. Terms actually in use include:

- engineering physicist
- engineer-physicist
- physicist-engineer

and others.